# ¿Cómo puedo darle estilo a un código?

Tags: html, css

¿Cómo funciona o cómo se hace para darle estilo a un código? Por ejemplo, **Stack Overflow**, cuando se inserta código automáticamente le da un estilo (pinta de color las palabras reservadas).

He estado investigando, pero no encuentro nada sobre esto.

Sé que de esta forma puedo darle color a una palabra, pero estar haciendo esto para todas las palabras que quiera resulta muy tedioso.

```css
pre {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

code {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.codigo {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <pre>
        <code>
<code class="codigo">while</code> True:
    print("Hola Mundo")
        </code>
    </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

¿Existe alguna otra forma?, como por ejemplo, se detecte el lenguaje y pinte todas sus palabras reservadas de un color.

Llevo poco tiempo aprendiendo **HTML** y **CSS**. Así que, no sé que título darle y si tengo que usar un **Framework** para poder hacer esto no tengo problemas; he estado viendo **Flask.**

Comment: Hola, no entiendo bien tu pregunta, te refieres a cambiar el color de los comandos de cada lenguaje en algún IDE (Entorno de Desarrollo Integrado)?

Comment: @NoéMuñoz no, estoy creando una pagina y en esa pagina tengo código y uso las etiquetas  `pre ` y `code` , el código se pinta de color blanco y me gustaría darle estilo a ese código pero solo a sus palabras reservadas, en el ejemplo que deje lo hago dándole estilo a la palabra while pero darle estilo a uno por una es tedioso

Comment: Pues entonces crea clases en css y las reutilizas

Comment: @SalvadorMellado y que tal si checas esto: https://highlightjs.org/ Opciones de bibliotecas hay muchas, te recomiendo googlear

Comment: @BetaM lo chequeare creo que es lo que busco

Comment: igual como dice la pregunta llevo poco tiempo con html y css por eso procedí a preguntar por que tampoco se como buscar algo como esto y si que lo intente.

Comment: Existen distintas librerías para dar color al código, una recomendación personal sería [prismJS](https://prismjs.com/), selecciona los lenguajes en los que trabajas y te dará el código tanto JS como CSS, y la magia estará hecha, para que se coloque el código tiene que estar dentro de una etiqueta _pre_ y dentro de esta una _code_, la etiqueta _pre_ debe tener una clase por ejemplo `language-javascript` y el código se acomodará para el lenguaje escrito

Comment: @anythingg lo malo es que genera mucho código.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Dejare una respuesta por si alguien le llega a servir.

Esto se le conoce como **resaltado de sintaxis**, y como me comentaron, existen muchas bibliotecas para esto. Empezando por la que me recomendaron: [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/).

Para usarla, primero tenemos que importar el CSS:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href=
"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/styles/default.min.css">
```

También es posible cambiar esta parte: `default.min.css`, por esto: `darcula.min.css`.

Esto nos permite ir cambiando los colores que se le va dando al código. Existen muchos otros estilos que podemos ir probando.

También es necesario importar estos dos **scripts,** de lo contrario, no funcionará.

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

Por último, tenemos que especificar el lenguaje. Aunque puede detectarlo automáticamente, es posible que falle en su detección.

```html
<pre>
    <code class="python">
     while True:
         print("hola mundo")
    </code>
</pre>
```

Resultado final:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/prueba.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/styles/dracula.min.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <pre>
  <code class="python">
  while True:
      print("hola mundo")
  </code>
  </pre>
</body>

</html>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

O sin instalar tantas cosas, y scripts exernos en nuestro sitio, con un simple CSS podemos obtener el siguiente resultado.

```css
pre {
background-color: #444;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444 50%, #505050 50%);
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(#444 50%, #505050 50%);
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(#444 50%, #505050 50%);
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(#444 50%, #505050 50%);
background-image:         linear-gradient(#444 50%, #505050 50%);
background-position: 0 1px;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: 48px 48px; /* background-size */
border-radius: 5px;
color: #fff5db; 
line-height: 24px;
padding: 24px;
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<pre>
pre {
background-color: #444;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444 50%, #505050 50%);
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(#444 50%, #505050 50%);
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(#444 50%, #505050 50%);
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(#444 50%, #505050 50%);
background-image:         linear-gradient(#444 50%, #505050 50%);
background-position: 0 1px;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: 48px 48px; /* background-size */
border-radius: 5px;
color: #fff5db; 
line-height: 24px;
padding: 24px;
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
text-align: justify;
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Disculpas esta en español ya mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

otra biblioteca que sirve para resaltar código es [code-prettify](https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify)

funciona casi igual, primero se importa el script.

```
<script  src = " https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/google/code-prettify@master/loader/run_prettify.js?skin=desert" > </script>
```

al final del script tambien podemos cambiar la [skin](https://raw.githack.com/google/code-prettify/master/styles/index.html), por ejemplo le puse el estilo desert ? `?skin=desert`

luego especificamos la clase `prettyprint` para la etiqueta `pre`, y por ultimo en la etiqueta `code` especificamos el lenguaje.

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
    <code class="lang-python">
        while True:
            print("hola mundo")
    </code>
</pre>
```

Resultado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Desert">
</head>
<body>
    <pre class="prettyprint">
        <code class="lang-python">
            while True:
                print("hola mundo")
        </code>
    </pre>
</body>

</html>

<script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/google/code-prettify@master/loader/run_prettify.js?skin=desert" defer = "" ></script>
```